# How to set file labels in p4merge

Tags: svn, perforce, p4merge

When p4merge is invoked from p4v it displays depot paths as labels on the files. I would like to use p4merge as a diff viewer for SVN, and to that end I have this batch file:

```
@echo off
pause
p4merge %6 %7
```

This works, but the labels appearing on the left and right panels are the names of the temporary files SVN has created to feed to p4merge. Arguments %3 and %5 that SVN passes to the batch file contain appropriate labels for the left and right panels respectively. I am sure I remember there being command-line arguments to set what labels you want to appear on each of the panels, but they are not listed by `p4merge -h`. What are they?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like the options I was looking for are `-nl NAME` to name the left pane and `-nr NAME` to name the right pane. So my batch file is now:

```
@echo off
pause
p4merge -nl %3 -nr %5 %6 %7
```

Comment: Cheers for undocumented parameters.

Comment: For those interested in renaming also the others panels for the merge:
**-nb** sets the label for the base file panel;
**-nm** sets the label for the merge file panel

Comment: Sorry to hijack your answer but for my own selfish gain I'm going to document my preferred TortoiseSVN Merge tool setting here so I'll find it again later.
"C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe" -nl "%tname (theirs)" -nr "%yname (mine)" -nb "%bname (base)" -nm "%mname (merged)" %base %theirs %mine %merged

Comment: Hey!! are there any undocumented parameters to change the font?